# hammerDB libmysqltcl.dll couldn't load

Tags: mysql, hammerdb

I installed hammerDB v4.6 on a AWS vm and I'm trying to connect to my aurora/mysql database on RDS, but when I start the schema build, I get this error
*Error in Virtual User 1: Error: Failed to load mysqltcl - couldn't load library "D:/Users/xyz/HammerDB-4.6-Win/HammerDB-4.6/lib/mysqltcl3.052/libmysqltcl.dll": this library or a dependent library could not be found in library path*

The libmysqltcl.dll is there. So it is probably a dependent library that is missing.
So I tried to install mysql server on the vm, expecting that this would install some missing dll. But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I simply copied libmysql.dll in HammerDB-4.6/bin